# Is there a bean called springSecurityFilterChain?

Tags: spring, spring-security

**Curiosity question**: Good day, I am studying Spring Security and it seems that there is a bean actually called "springSecurityFilterChain". A search on the web for `No bean named ‘springSecurityFilterChain’ is defined` returns a bunch of results and solutions on how to fix the problem. **Note**: I am not experiencing the problem, just curious.

Now, I have tried looking for that bean, either in the Root context of a Spring MVC app or in the WebApplicationContex context, but there is no springSecurityFilterChain bean. There is an actual Spring Security chain, yes, but no bean.

So, any insight is appreciated. More notes below.

To test, I am playing with a sample app from the samples in a PactkPub spring security book. Standard configuration:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The delegating filter proxy, will proxy to the springSecurityFilterChain. All clear, but no bean named springSecurityFilterChain.

Here is the code I used to fetch the beans:

```
    ApplicationContext parent = applicationContext.getParent();
    System.out.println(parent.getDisplayName());
    System.out.println("Beans in parent = " + parent.getBeanDefinitionCount());
    int i = 0;
    for (String beanName : parent.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        System.out.println("Bean in parent: " + i + ": " +
                beanName + " : " +
                parent.getBean(beanName).getClass().toString());
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("Context: " + applicationContext.getDisplayName());
    System.out.println("Beans in context = " + applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionCount());
    i = 0;
    for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        System.out.println("Bean in child: " + i + ": " +
                beanName + " : " +
                applicationContext.getBean(beanName).getClass().toString());
        i++;
    }
```

The beans registered list is:

```
Root WebApplicationContext
Beans in parent = 39
Bean in parent: 0: jdbcEventDao : class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14
Bean in parent: 1: jdbcCalendarUserDao : class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15
Bean in parent: 2: defaultCalendarService : class com.packtpub.springsecurity.service.DefaultCalendarService
Bean in parent: 3: userContextStub : class com.packtpub.springsecurity.service.UserContextStub
Bean in parent: 4: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor
Bean in parent: 5: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
Bean in parent: 6: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
Bean in parent: 7: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
Bean in parent: 8: org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator : class org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator
Bean in parent: 9: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0 : class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource
Bean in parent: 10: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0 : class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor
Bean in parent: 11: org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor : class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor
Bean in parent: 12: dataSource : class org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource
Bean in parent: 13: transactionManager : class org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager
Bean in parent: 14: jdbcTemplate : class org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
Bean in parent: 15: messageSource : class org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource
Bean in parent: 16: org.springframework.security.filterChains : class java.util.ArrayList
Bean in parent: 17: org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy : class org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
Bean in parent: 18: org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0 : class org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain
Bean in parent: 19: org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0 : class org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl
Bean in parent: 20: org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0 : class org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
Bean in parent: 21: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0 : class org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
Bean in parent: 22: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0 : class org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository
Bean in parent: 23: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0 : class org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy
Bean in parent: 24: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0 : class org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache
Bean in parent: 25: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0 : class org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler
Bean in parent: 26: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0 : class org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased
Bean in parent: 27: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0 : class org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
Bean in parent: 28: org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0 : class org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator
Bean in parent: 29: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0 : class org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider
Bean in parent: 30: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0 : class org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint
Bean in parent: 31: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0 : class org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
Bean in parent: 32: org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory : class org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean
Bean in parent: 33: org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1 : class org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain
Bean in parent: 34: org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager#0 : class org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager
Bean in parent: 35: org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0 : class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
Bean in parent: 36: org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0 : class org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher
Bean in parent: 37: org.springframework.security.authenticationManager : class org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
Bean in parent: 38: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0 : class org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor
Context: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet-servlet'
Beans in context = 23
Bean in child: 0: eventsController : class com.packtpub.springsecurity.web.controllers.EventsController
Bean in child: 1: welcomeController : class com.packtpub.springsecurity.web.controllers.WelcomeController
Bean in child: 2: defaultController : class com.packtpub.springsecurity.web.controllers.DefaultController
Bean in child: 3: webMvcConfig : class com.packtpub.springsecurity.web.config.WebMvcConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2f942b5a
Bean in child: 4: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor
Bean in child: 5: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
Bean in child: 6: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
Bean in child: 7: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
Bean in child: 8: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0 : class org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor
Bean in child: 9: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration#0 : class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1dfc2733
Bean in child: 10: requestMappingHandlerMapping : class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
Bean in child: 11: viewControllerHandlerMapping : class org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping
Bean in child: 12: beanNameHandlerMapping : class org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping
Bean in child: 13: resourceHandlerMapping : class org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping
Bean in child: 14: defaultServletHandlerMapping : class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping
Bean in child: 15: requestMappingHandlerAdapter : class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
Bean in child: 16: mvcConversionService : class org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService
Bean in child: 17: mvcValidator : class org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean
Bean in child: 18: httpRequestHandlerAdapter : class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter
Bean in child: 19: simpleControllerHandlerAdapter : class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter
Bean in child: 20: handlerExceptionResolver : class org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite
Bean in child: 21: contentNegotiatingViewResolver : class org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
Bean in child: 22: internalResolver : class org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the answer: **springSecurityFilterChain** is not the actual name of the bean, but rather an alias. This gets converted to the actual or canonical name by the function **AbstractBeanFactory.transformedBeanName** which takes the alias **springSecurityFilterChain** and returns **org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy**

The approximate pseudo-call chain is

```
DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean()
 DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(webapplicationcontext wac)
  Filter delegate = wac.getBean(getTargetBeanName(), Filter.class)
   ..
   AbtractBeanFactory.doGetBean(name)  // name here is springSecurityFilterChain
    beanName = AbstractBeanFactory.transformedBeanName(name)
```

The function transformedBeanName is quite simple and basically calls canonicalName:

```
protected String transformedBeanName(String name) {
    return canonicalName(BeanFactoryUtils.transformedBeanName(name));
}
```

canonicalName, which is a method of the class SimpleAliasRegistry looks in a hash map called aliasMap, which has exactly one entry for springSecurityFilterChain.